How to import Test cases from a CSV file into JIRA Xray Test repository using python
Does anybody know how to import Test cases from a CSV File to a Test repository in JIRA XRAY using Python?
I am currently receiving response 500 every time I run my code, failing to add test cases
My script currently authenticates with JIRA using a Personal Access Token, however wont import the TC's to xray. I have been utilising the JIRA REST API

Hey Arjun, to be able to help you out, are you using Xray on Jira Cloud or Xray on Jira datacenter (on-premises)? Xray Cloud instances URL are usually something like https://whatever.atlassian.net . If you don't know, you can ask your Jira/instance administrator.

and please, can you share the exact request you're doing with a sample copy of your request and the content you're trying to submit?
